# How to reprompt for invalid Boolean input (java)

Tags: java, boolean

When I run the program if I type something other than "true" or "false" it throws a InputMismatchException.

```
do {
            System.out.print("Do passengers have an individual tv screen?"
                    + "(true OR false): ");
            hasVideo = keyboard.nextBoolean();
            bus.setIndividualVideo(hasVideo);
            } while (!(hasVideo == true) && !(hasVideo == false));
```

Answer (score 2):

Catch the error and treat it as a invalid response...

```
try {
    System.out.print("Do passengers have an individual tv screen?"
                + "(true OR false): ");
    hasVideo = keyboard.nextBoolean();
} catch (InputMismatchException exp) {
    System.err.println("Please, enter only true or false");
}
```

Take a look at [The try Block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) for more details

Answer (score 1):

Aha, time to learn about `Exception` handling! Any of the `Exception` types that you see when java crashes can in fact be caught inside the program with a `try-catch` block.

```
try {
    // code that might throw exceptions 1
    // code that might throw exceptions 2
} catch (Exception e) {
    // do something to fix the error
}
```

If any code in the `try{ }` part does throw an `Exception` then it will *immediately* skip to the `catch( ) { }` part, skipping any other statements in the `try{ }`.

Your code with a `try-catch` would look like:

```
boolean loopAgain = false;
do {
    try {
        System.out.print("Do passengers have an individual tv screen?"
                + "(true OR false): ");
        hasVideo = keyboard.nextBoolean();
        bus.setIndividualVideo(hasVideo);

        loopAgain = false;

    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.err.println("Please, enter only true or false");
        loopAgain = true;
    }

} while (loopAgain);
```

**Edit:** I borrowed the `println("Please, enter only true or false");` from @MadProgrammer's  answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to prompt the user to enter a Boolean value.  Because `nextBoolean()` can throw an exception, the best thing to do is to put that code inside a try/catch. The catch block code is only executed if anything other than true or false is entered.  You can add a `while()` or `do/while()` loop to keep telling the user to try again.  However, the most important thing to do in the `catch` block is to flush the input stream.  Remember, even though there was an exception, the stream still contains stuff in it.  It has to be properly consumed before using again. The code below should do exactly what you are looking for:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Boolean answer = null;
    do
    {
        System.out.println("Enter either true or false");
        try
        {
            answer = input.nextBoolean();
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException e)
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR: The input provided is not a valid boolean value. Try again...");
            input.next(); // flush the stream
        }
    } while(answer == null);
    input.close();
}
```